# how can I get a value from the nth element of the closest 'tr'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

I have a dynamic table that contains price, quantity and subtotal on each row. I am trying to write a javascript method that automatically multiples the price and quantity values on each keyup and outputs them as the subtotal.

```
$('input.value').keyup( function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var val1 = row.find(':nth-child(1)').value;
        var val2 = row.find(':nth-child(2)').value;
        console.log(val1);
        console.log(val2);
        output = row.find(':nth-child(3)');
        output.value = val1 * val2;
    });
```

This is as far as I've gotten so far, the console log just shows "undefined" as the values for val1, and val2. Why is this? Am I misunderstanding how .find() works?

I have tried searching on both stack exchange and google, and I can't seem to find a good example of using nth-child based on the currently selected row.

Here is a simplified version of the table row. Each table row has an id based on it's row number.

```
<tr id = "row_#">
<td>
    <?php echo $this->Form->text("Items.{$key}.quantity", array('value' => $item['quantity'], 'class' => 'value')); ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $this->Form->text("Items.{$key}.price", array('value' => $item['price'], 'class' => 'value')); ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $this->Form->text("Items.{$key}.total", array('value' => number_format( $item['price']*$item['quantity'], 2), 'class' => 'subtotal')); ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am using jquery, and cakephp 2.7

Comment: It seems that `row.find(':nth-child(1)')` will select a `<td>`, but you want to be selecting the `<input>` inside the `<td>`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is there any way to select the nth input? Or do I have to do something like row.find('nth-child(1)').find('nth-child(1)').value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `row.find(':nth-child(1)')` selects a `<td>` element -- the first child of the `<tr>`. But it seems that you want to select `<input>` elements in each row to get their values.

In my example, below, I've given each input a class that identifies it as a "quantity", "price", or "total" field. I find the closest row to the current `<input>`. Then I find the value for each input within that row, calculate the total, and set the value of the "total" `<input>` to that number.

I'm using jQuery's [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context), which is internally equivalent to `find()`.

```js
$('input.value').keyup(function() {
  
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
      $output = jQuery('input.total', $row),
      quantity = jQuery('input.quantity', $row).val(),
      price = jQuery('input.price', $row).val(),
      total = quantity * price;

  $output.val(total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value quantity" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value price" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value quantity" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value price" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value quantity" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value price" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use `nth-child` selectors rather than classes, if you prefer. But remember that "nth" children are the `<td>` elements, not the `<input>` elements. You'll need to select the `<input>` within each "nth" `<td>` child. Something like:

```
$row.find('td:nth-child(1) input').val()
```

See the example below:

```js
$('input.value').keyup(function() {
  
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
      $output = $row.find('td:nth-child(3) input'),
      quantity = $row.find('td:nth-child(1) input').val(),
      price = $row.find('td:nth-child(2) input').val(),
      total = quantity * price;

  $output.val(total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no `value` property....use `val()` and assuming selectors are valid it should work

```
var val1 = row.find(':nth-child(1)').val();
```

Comment: Ah yes, it seems that I need to use .val(). The selector is invalid though. Is there a way to find the nth 'input' (since <input> is apparently inside each <td> element), or do I have to find the n-th child of the n-th child to get the input field?