# How to get text of form child when an input element is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my `HTML` layout. I have multiple forms:

```
 <table>
     <form>
         <tr>
             <td id="1">Text1</td>
             <td id="2">Text2</td>
             <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit1">
         </tr>
     </form>
     <form>
         <tr>
             <td id="1">Text1</td>
             <td id="2">Text2</td>
             <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit2">
         </tr>
     </form>

</table>
```

What I want is to fetch the text in between the `<td>` of `id=1`. What I have done is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).closest("form").find('td first').text());
    }); 
});
```

Comment: use the id of the td `$("#1")`. **since ID should be unique it should do the work**. Also dont start an ID with a number. if you have many rows with this format use class instead and then use `$(this).closest(tr).find("td:nth-child(1)")`

Comment: the problem is that I have multiple forms. So, what I want is the id specific to the child of that form

Comment: ***if you have many rows with this format use class instead*** and then use `$(this).closest(tr).find("td:nth-child(1)")` or `$(this).parent(tr).find("td:nth-child(1)")` note `:nth-child()` index starts with 1 if using `.eq()` index starts with 0

Comment: @guradio Great It works.

Comment: glad to help mate happy coding :)

Comment: @guradio That ought to be a proper answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Pharap i would answer it but i was looking for a duplicate it is better but i cant find a dup right now

Comment: @guradio The closest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616408/1377706). So I suspect there isn't a suitable duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I get a value from the nth element of the closest 'tr'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616207/how-can-i-get-a-value-from-the-nth-element-of-the-closest-tr)

Comment: @Pharap thank you i cant find a correct way to find a dup :)

Comment: @guradio I found that by doing a Google search on the code you posted so it would find similar code - a good trick to bear in mind. (Personally I'm not sure whether it counts as a duplicate or not, but it's certainly the closest I could find.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id*="submit"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('form').find('td').first().text());
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="form1-1">Form 1: Text1</td>
      <td id="form1-2">Text2</td>
       <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit1">
     </tr>
 </table>
</form>
<form>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td id="form2-1">Form 2: Text1</td>
     <td id="form2-2">Text2</td>
     <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit2">
   </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

There are few thing to notice in your code

- `id` should be unique
- `form` tag should be outside the `table`

Hope this will you.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right! It should be

```
$(this).closest("form").find('td#1').text()
```

You might consider not using id's in this context; they are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should may be prefer class than id, iike what `Julia Finarovsky` said, `id` should be unique.

You almost got it right, though you just forgot `:` in between `td` and `first` in the `find param`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).closest("form").find('td:first').text());
    }); 
});
```

Hope this helps.